# AWS_CDK.AWS_ECS: Cluster container instance with wrong configurations for EC2 launch-type

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk

I need to create EC2 launch-type ecs by using below code

```
class ECSStack(cdk.Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: cdk.Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(
            scope,
            construct_id,
            env=cdk.Environment(
                account=<MY_ACCOUNT_NO>,
                region=<MY_REGION>
            )
        )

        self.vpc = Vpc.from_lookup(
            self,
            "lookup-vpc",
            vpc_id="vpc-0fd27cbc0cb8c8ed1"
        )
        self.security_group = SecurityGroup.from_lookup(
            self,
            "lookup-security-group",
            security_group_id="sg-0ba340103bfb50fa1"
        )
        self.subnet = Subnet.from_subnet_attributes(
            self,
            "lookup-subnet",
            subnet_id="subnet-0fb04718abce46fe0"
        )

        self.create_cluster()


    def create_cluster(self) -> None:
            self.cluster = Cluster(
                self,
                config.CLUSTER_ID,
                vpc=self.vpc
            )
            Cluster.from_cluster_attributes(
                self,
                "plts-production-cluster_attributes",
                cluster_name=config.CLUSTER_CAPACITY_ID,
                security_groups=[self.security_group],
                vpc=self.vpc
            )
            self.cluster.add_capacity(
                config.CLUSTER_CAPACITY_ID,
                instance_type=InstanceType(config.CLUSTER_CAPACITY_INSTANCE_TYPE),
                key_name=config.SSH_KEY_NAME
            )
```

The problem for me are below

1. The cluster created is Fargate instead of EC2 launch-type(sample code in python install package suggest this to create EC2-launch-type one but does not work)
2. There is no way(also no need according to sample code) to specify IAM role which should be ecsInstanceRole including AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role policy. So the IAM role used by container instance is new created with other inline policy.
3. The security_group configured to container instance is also new created though I specify existing one.

Here I attach sample code from python install package.
To use tasks with Amazon EC2 launch-type, you have to add capacity to
the cluster in order for tasks to be scheduled on your instances.  Typically,
you add an AutoScalingGroup with instances running the latest
Amazon ECS-optimized AMI to the cluster. There is a method to build and add such an
AutoScalingGroup automatically, or you can supply a customized AutoScalingGroup
that you construct yourself. It's possible to add multiple AutoScalingGroups
with various instance types.

The following example creates an Amazon ECS cluster and adds capacity to it:

````
```python
# Example automatically generated without compilation. See https://github.com/aws/jsii/issues/826
cluster = ecs.Cluster(self, "Cluster",
    vpc=vpc
)

# Either add default capacity
cluster.add_capacity("DefaultAutoScalingGroupCapacity",
    instance_type=ec2.InstanceType("t2.xlarge"),
    desired_capacity=3
)

# Or add customized capacity. Be sure to start the Amazon ECS-optimized AMI.
auto_scaling_group = autoscaling.AutoScalingGroup(self, "ASG",
    vpc=vpc,
    instance_type=ec2.InstanceType("t2.xlarge"),
    machine_image=EcsOptimizedImage.amazon_linux(),
    # Or use Amazon ECS-Optimized Amazon Linux 2 AMI
    # machineImage: EcsOptimizedImage.amazonLinux2(),
    desired_capacity=3
)

cluster.add_auto_scaling_group(auto_scaling_group)
```

If you omit the property `vpc`, the construct will create a new VPC with two AZs.
````

Environment
CDK CLI Version: 1.98.0
Module Version: 1.98.0
Node.js Version: 12.19.0
OS: Windows 10
Language (Version): Python 3.8.2

Comment: Please don't post code or error messages as screenshot, but properly formatted code blocks.

Comment: screenshots removed and code block added